# Why does this while-loop in C not work?

Tags: c

Ignoring the fact that negative numbers would not work here, why do positive integers create a infinite loop? I tried many combinations, as simple as a = 20 and b = 4, but every single one creates a infinite loop. What am I doing wrong or not seeing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mdc(int a, int b) {
while (a != b) {
    if (a > b) 
        a = a - b;
    else b = b - a;
}
return a;
}

int main() {
    int a, b;
    printf("Valores mdc: \n");
    scanf("%d %d\n", &a, &b);
    printf("%d\n", mdc(a,b));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, check that `a` and `b` where initialized by checking the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Have you tried printing the values inside the loop? If not, do it.

Comment: I get it..this is a nice question..will answer

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Ok, actual problem is really in the scanf(). Problem relates to @Iharob Al Asimi comment. Made a slight change and it is working well, thing is, after the input, he still asks me for another line of something, can that be related to the '\n' I have in the scanf function?

Comment: Well, thanks @alk, indeed program debugging is something I have not yet looked at.

Comment: Yeah, problem was with '\n' on scanf now, all fixed, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @PedroCosta.: It's not about the error always but think someday why did it happen because of that `\n`. This will help you. :)

Comment: Someone said something about the break statement but deleted. In fact, it saves a lot of iterations if it stops when a is a multiple of b. Thing is, is there any quick way to make that check or do I need to make a side-program? How can I write a condition that checks if it is an integer or a float in C?

Comment: @coderredoc most of this answers actually helped me compreend that error, it was actually something so logic, but as I said, I just couldn't see it.

Comment: @PedroCosta you should stop trying to write code until you learn how to debug, the easiest way is to find out how to use you debugger to step in, step over, breakpoint and inspect variable values.  If you cannot debug, you cannot program:(

Comment: @MartinJames, I'm afraid you are goint too far.  A debugger is a nice tool to program, but it isn't in anyway, fundamental to learn to program.  I had to learn to program without a debugger, mainly because when I learnt there was no one available for my platform.  You are not right this time.  Learning to program without a debugger is a good exercise today to see how difficult was in the old times.

Comment: @LuisColorado what 'old times'?  I have to support a legacy embedded system where 'printf debug' over the serial port is all that is available:)   If, however, the OP does have a reasonable environment, and a debugger is available, then s/he should surely use it!  That would cut down on the number of 'debug my code' posts on SO.

Comment: I learnt with turbo pascal 3.0 which hadn't a debugger at all... You had to put traces in the code if you wanted to see anything happening.  Anyway, learning to not depend on the debugger is also a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Not an infinite loop for the given input:-

The thing is you have used `\n` in the `scanf` as a result unless you enter some non-whitespace character - it waits for it.

#### What did the `'\n'` do?

From standard explaining the *why* part - C11 N1570 §[**7.21.6.2**¶**5**](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p5)

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is **executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character** (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails.

#### How to give input then?

So it will work if you do this:-

```
>>> 20  4 Enter
<Somenonwhitespace> Enter
```

#### Better solution:

Even better suggestion would be to use

```
scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
```

You don't need to specify the space as you did - `%d` directive skips over the white space characters.

Code wise

```
if(scanf("%d%d", &a, &b)!=2){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were to step the code in a debugger you would discover that the while loop is never even entered.  It is not a problem of an infinite while-loop.  Rather that `scanf()` never returns.

Change:

```
scanf("%d %d\n", &a, &b);
```

to

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `scanf("%d %d\n", &a, &b);` should be `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);` no `\n`.